# Can we handle more than one exception with switchIfEmpty in Reactor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, exceptionhandler

I am using Mono to retrieve some user with my controller. I have this code

`Mono.just(userId) .flatMap(repo::findById) .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new UserBadRequestExeception()))`

And I have a test for it which is working, but I would like to write a test for user not found and this is the code :

`client.post() .uri("/user/invalid") .bodyValue(request) .exchange() .expectStatus() .isNotFound() .expectBody() .jsonPath("code").isEqualTo("404") .jsonPath("message").isEqualTo("Not Found") .jsonPath("description").isEqualTo("404 NOT_FOUND") .jsonPath("instance").exists();` 
But it gives me

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "code".
```

I tried with onErrorResume but without luck. Can we handle one then more exception in the Mono/Flux?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not? `Mono.error` is capable of accepting a `Supplier` object.

It's unclear what your exception cases would be, but you can handle as many cases as you need:

```
Mono.just(userId) 
  .flatMap(repo::findById)
  .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> {
     if(isBadRequest) {
       return new UserBadRequestExeception();
     } else if(notFound) { 
       return new UserNotFoundException();
     } else { 
       return new GenericException();
     }
  }));
```